# how to get nearest positions

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, bing-maps

I'm developing app with geolocalization. I want to display on my map (for example) stores that are nearest of my current position. I have lati and longitude saved for each store in my db and I have current position of user. Now I want to get from db nearest positions from me in arial of my zoom.

I don't want to pick them all cause if I'll have 10000 positions adding them to db (like also getting them from db) will be long and cpu consuming. Thats why I want to pick only those that can be displayed on map.

Map is centered on my current position. How to get them ? How to count this ?

Comment: If you have the extents of the view of the map, what do you need beyond "use `<` to filter the coordinates"?

Comment: imo much. Cause if my current localization is 51.133731/22.111321 How I know what diffrence is 1 km if I want to pick positions from 1km area ?

Comment: You can either compute the actual distance, or overestimate and use 112km/degree (which is roughly the maximum number of kilometers in a degree of latitude or longitude).  If you just need to filter a large data set quickly, using the estimate is probably good enough.  The math to compute the actual isn't particularly tricky, but that question would be better suited to [the GIS StackExchange site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If using sql server, it has built in geospatial functions to handle this exact scenario.

Comment: @JeffBrand-MSFT did you Geography datatype ?

Comment: Been awhile since I worked with it, but if IIRC. yes

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the distance between any two points of latitude and longitude using the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).  You could build a stored procedure (even a [CLR stored procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx)) that takes the current location and a distance and computes all the points within that area.